# How plot in gnuplot one curve from multiple data files with modifications?

Tags: gnuplot

I want plot in gnuplot one curve using multiple data files in format like this:

dat1.dat

```
time x y
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

dat2.dat

```
time1 x1 y1
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
```

I want draw one curve in that way: (`time`, `x`) and (`time1`, `x*5`) combine together.

I know that I can do something like that:

```
plot "dat1.dat" using 1:2, \
     "dat2.dat" using 1:($2*5)
```

and this is nearly what I want to have, but then, I've got two curves with two titles in legend, different colors. I want to have one curve in the single graph with one title in legend.

Comment: What do you already know of plotting? And what did you already try?

Answer (score 1):

If you want both lines to have the same linetype you must set it explicitely. Also, to have only a single legend, set the title only for the first plot, and unset it for the second plot:

```
plot "dat1.dat" using 1:2 linetype 1 title "data",\
     "dat2.dat" using 1:($2*5) linetype 1 notitle`
```